# flutter_bloc/provider RepositoryProvider vs Provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-bloc

Im new to flutter and currently figuring out DI.
I am using `flutter_bloc` and `provider` packages.

`flutter_bloc` ships with a `RepositoryProvider`, the question im asking myself now is whats the diffrence to `Provider` from `provider`?

**Is there anything special to `RepositoryProvider` repositories or is it just a naming strategy?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [RepositoryProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/RepositoryProvider-class.html) does not handle updates.
  You cannot "change" the repository at runtime.
- [Provider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Provider-class.html) does handle updates (using `Provider.value`). This means if you change the object at runtime, then the widgets which use it will rebuild.

The impact of this difference is on life-cycles like `initState`:

Using [Provider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Provider-class.html), you have to explicitly *not* listen to the object changes:

```dart
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  // will fail if listen: false is not specified
  Provider.of<MyObject>(context, listen: false);
}
```

Using [RepositoryProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/RepositoryProvider-class.html), you don't have to care:

```dart
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  RepositoryProvider.of<MyObject>(context);
}
```

So this is only a difference in verbosity.

In fact, since [Provider version 4.1.0](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#410), you can use `context.read<MyObject>()` instead of `Provider.of<MyObject>(context, listen: false)` – which reduces the verbosity difference

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the previous commenter. `RepositoryProvider` handle updates.
`RepositoryProvider` is a slightly modified `Provider` version.

1. There is no `dispose()` method. Repositories should ideally not have a
   lifecycle and should not maintain internal state. All
   lifecycle-related code and state should be maintained in
   blocs/cubits.
2. The static method `RepositoryProvider.of(context)` has default `listen`
   parameter set to `false`.

You can use `RepositoryProvider.of(context)` method with `Provider` and `Provider.of(context)` method with `RepositoryProvider`.

`MultiRepositoryProvider` and `MultiProvider` is the same.